# quasar build gives error: vite.createFilter is not a function

Tags: node.js, vue.js, quasar

`quasar build` gives vite error.

From the last issue, [quasar: When building an app it gives vite error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75422050/quasar-when-building-an-app-it-gives-vite-error). I have changed "vite": "^3" to "vite": "2.9.14" in package.json , that resolved that last error, though now I'm getting a new one

```
deb2302user@deb2302:~/tmp2303/vue/kitty$ quasar build

 .d88888b.
d88P" "Y88b
888     888
888     888 888  888  8888b.  .d8888b   8888b.  888d888
888     888 888  888     "88b 88K          "88b 888P"
888 Y8b 888 888  888 .d888888 "Y8888b. .d888888 888
Y88b.Y8b88P Y88b 888 888  888      X88 888  888 888
 "Y888888"   "Y88888 "Y888888  88888P' "Y888888 888
       Y8b


 Build mode............. spa
 Pkg quasar............. v2.11.3
 Pkg @quasar/app-vite... v1.1.3
 Pkg vite............... v2.9.14
 Debugging.............. no
 Publishing............. no

 App • Cleaned build artifact: "/home/deb2302user/tmp2303/vue/kitty/dist/spa"
/home/deb2302user/tmp2303/vue/kitty/node_modules/.pnpm/@vitejs+plugin-vue-jsx@3.0.0_vite@2.9.14+vue@3.2.45/node_modules/@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx/dist/index.cjs:40
  const filter = vite.createFilter(include || /\.[jt]sx$/, exclude);
                      ^

TypeError: vite.createFilter is not a function
    at vueJsxPlugin (/home/deb2302user/tmp2303/vue/kitty/node_modules/.pnpm/@vitejs+plugin-vue-jsx@3.0.0_vite@2.9.14+vue@3.2.45/node_modules/@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx/dist/index.cjs:40:23)
    at /home/deb2302user/tmp2303/vue/kitty/node_modules/.pnpm/@quasar+app-vite@1.1.3_lezvi6egse7w7wgglmky3dvexq/node_modules/@quasar/app-vite/lib/config-tools.js:70:40
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at parseVitePlugins (/home/deb2302user/tmp2303/vue/kitty/node_modules/.pnpm/@quasar+app-vite@1.1.3_lezvi6egse7w7wgglmky3dvexq/node_modules/@quasar/app-vite/lib/config-tools.js:25:11)
    at createViteConfig (/home/deb2302user/tmp2303/vue/kitty/node_modules/.pnpm/@quasar+app-vite@1.1.3_lezvi6egse7w7wgglmky3dvexq/node_modules/@quasar/app-vite/lib/config-tools.js:137:10)
    at Object.vite (/home/deb2302user/tmp2303/vue/kitty/node_modules/.pnpm/@quasar+app-vite@1.1.3_lezvi6egse7w7wgglmky3dvexq/node_modules/@quasar/app-vite/lib/modes/spa/spa-config.js:6:17)
    at SpaBuilder.build (/home/deb2302user/tmp2303/vue/kitty/node_modules/.pnpm/@quasar+app-vite@1.1.3_lezvi6egse7w7wgglmky3dvexq/node_modules/@quasar/app-vite/lib/modes/spa/spa-builder.js:7:37)
    at build (/home/deb2302user/tmp2303/vue/kitty/node_modules/.pnpm/@quasar+app-vite@1.1.3_lezvi6egse7w7wgglmky3dvexq/node_modules/@quasar/app-vite/lib/cmd/build.js:162:14)

Node.js v18.14.0
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "kitty",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "description": "Kitty desc",
  "author": "amirny2205 <amirny2205@yandex.ru>",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts,.vue ./",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,ts,vue,scss,html,md,json}\" --ignore-path .gitignore",
    "test": "echo \"No test specified\" && exit 0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@quasar/extras": "^1.0.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx": "^3.0.0",
    "@vue/babel-plugin-jsx": "^1.1.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^5.0.8",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^3.7.0",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "jquery": "^3.6.3",
    "pinia": "^2.0.11",
    "quasar": "^2.6.0",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-i18n": "^9.2.2",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@intlify/vite-plugin-vue-i18n": "^3.3.1",
    "@quasar/app-vite": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.21",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.10.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.10.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
    "eslint": "^8.10.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.5.1",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4",
    "vite": "2.9.14"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "^18 || ^16 || ^14.19",
    "npm": ">= 6.13.4",
    "yarn": ">= 1.21.1"
  },
  "productName": "Kitty"
}
```

quasar.config.js

```
/* eslint-env node */

/*
 * This file runs in a Node context (it's NOT transpiled by Babel), so use only
 * the ES6 features that are supported by your Node version. https://node.green/
 */

// Configuration for your app
// https://v2.quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/quasar-config-js

const { configure } = require('quasar/wrappers');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = configure(function (/* ctx */) {
  return {
    eslint: {
      // fix: true,
      // include = [],
      // exclude = [],
      // rawOptions = {},
      warnings: true,
      errors: true
    },

    // https://v2.quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/prefetch-feature
    // preFetch: true,

    // app boot file (/src/boot)
    // --> boot files are part of "main.js"
    // https://v2.quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/boot-files
    boot: [
      'i18n',
      'axios',
    ],

    // https://v2.quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/quasar-config-js#css
    css: [
      'app.scss'
    ],

    // https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/tree/dev/extras
    extras: [
      // 'ionicons-v4',
      // 'mdi-v5',
      // 'fontawesome-v6',
      // 'eva-icons',
      // 'themify',
      // 'line-awesome',
      // 'roboto-font-latin-ext', // this or either 'roboto-font', NEVER both!

      'roboto-font', // optional, you are not bound to it
      'material-icons', // optional, you are not bound to it
      'material-icons-outlined',
    ],

    // Full list of options: https://v2.quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/quasar-config-js#build
    build: {
      target: {
        browser: [ 'es2019', 'edge88', 'firefox78', 'chrome87', 'safari13.1' ],
        node: 'node16'
      },

      vueRouterMode: 'history', // available values: 'hash', 'history'
      // vueRouterBase,
      // vueDevtools,
      // vueOptionsAPI: false,

      // rebuildCache: true, // rebuilds Vite/linter/etc cache on startup

      // publicPath: '/',
      // analyze: true,
      // env: {},
      // rawDefine: {}
      // ignorePublicFolder: true,
      // minify: false,
      // polyfillModulePreload: true,
      // distDir

      // extendViteConf (viteConf) {},
      // viteVuePluginOptions: {},

      vitePlugins: [
        ['@intlify/vite-plugin-vue-i18n', {
          // if you want to use Vue I18n Legacy API, you need to set `compositionOnly: false`
          // compositionOnly: false,

          // you need to set i18n resource including paths !
          include: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/i18n/**')
        }
    ],
    ['@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx', {}
      ]
      ]
    },

    // Full list of options: https://v2.quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/quasar-config-js#devServer
    devServer: {
      // https: true
      open: true // opens browser window automatically
    },

    // https://v2.quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/quasar-config-js#framework
    framework: {
      config: {},

      // iconSet: 'material-icons', // Quasar icon set
      // lang: 'en-US', // Quasar language pack

      // For special cases outside of where the auto-import strategy can have an impact
      // (like functional components as one of the examples),
      // you can manually specify Quasar components/directives to be available everywhere:
      //
      components: [
        'QLayout',
    'QHeader',
    'QDrawer',
    'QPageContainer',
    'QPage',
    'QToolbar',
    'QToolbarTitle',
    'QBtn',
    'QBtnGroup',
    'QIcon',
    'QList',
    'QItem',
    'QItemSection',
    'QItemLabel',
    'QTooltip',
    'QInput',
    'QCard',
    'QCardSection',
    'QCardActions',
    'QDialog',
    'QForm',
    'QFooter',
    'QAvatar',
    'QScrollArea',
    'QImg',
    'QTabs',
    'QTab',
    'QRouteTab',
    'QTabPanels',
    'QTabPanel',
    'QFab',
    'QFabAction',
    'QSeparator',
    'QBar',
    'QSpace',
    'QSelect',
    'QRadio',
    'QTime',
    'QDate',
    'QPopupProxy',
    'QTable',
    'QTh',
    'QTr',
    'QTd',
    'QCheckbox',
    'QToggle',
    'QSpinnerHourglass',
    'QPageSticky',
    'QTimeline',
    'QTimelineEntry',
    'QBadge',
    'QStepper',
    'QStep',
    'QStepperNavigation',
    'QMenu',
      ],
      directives: [
    'ClosePopup'
      ],

      // Quasar plugins
      plugins: [
    'Notify'
      ]
    },

    // animations: 'all', // --- includes all animations
    // https://v2.quasar.dev/options/animations
    animations: [],

    // https://v2.quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/quasar-config-js#sourcefiles
    // sourceFiles: {
    //   rootComponent: 'src/App.vue',
    //   router: 'src/router/index',
    //   store: 'src/store/index',
    //   registerServiceWorker: 'src-pwa/register-service-worker',
    //   serviceWorker: 'src-pwa/custom-service-worker',
    //   pwaManifestFile: 'src-pwa/manifest.json',
    //   electronMain: 'src-electron/electron-main',
    //   electronPreload: 'src-electron/electron-preload'
    // },

    // https://v2.quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/developing-ssr/configuring-ssr
    ssr: {
      // ssrPwaHtmlFilename: 'offline.html', // do NOT use index.html as name!
                                          // will mess up SSR

      // extendSSRWebserverConf (esbuildConf) {},
      // extendPackageJson (json) {},

      pwa: false,

      // manualStoreHydration: true,
      // manualPostHydrationTrigger: true,

      prodPort: 3000, // The default port that the production server should use
                      // (gets superseded if process.env.PORT is specified at runtime)

      middlewares: [
        'render' // keep this as last one
      ]
    },

    // https://v2.quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/developing-pwa/configuring-pwa
    pwa: {
      workboxMode: 'generateSW', // or 'injectManifest'
      injectPwaMetaTags: true,
      swFilename: 'sw.js',
      manifestFilename: 'manifest.json',
      useCredentialsForManifestTag: false,
      // useFilenameHashes: true,
      // extendGenerateSWOptions (cfg) {}
      // extendInjectManifestOptions (cfg) {},
      // extendManifestJson (json) {}
      // extendPWACustomSWConf (esbuildConf) {}
    },

    // Full list of options: https://v2.quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/developing-cordova-apps/configuring-cordova
    cordova: {
      // noIosLegacyBuildFlag: true, // uncomment only if you know what you are doing
    },

    // Full list of options: https://v2.quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/developing-capacitor-apps/configuring-capacitor
    capacitor: {
      hideSplashscreen: true
    },

    // Full list of options: https://v2.quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/developing-electron-apps/configuring-electron
    electron: {
      // extendElectronMainConf (esbuildConf)
      // extendElectronPreloadConf (esbuildConf)

      inspectPort: 5858,

      bundler: 'packager', // 'packager' or 'builder'

      packager: {
        // https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager/blob/master/docs/api.md#options

        // OS X / Mac App Store
        // appBundleId: '',
        // appCategoryType: '',
        // osxSign: '',
        // protocol: 'myapp://path',

        // Windows only
        // win32metadata: { ... }
      },

      builder: {
        // https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration

        appId: 'kitty'
      }
    },

    // Full list of options: https://v2.quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/developing-browser-extensions/configuring-bex
    bex: {
      contentScripts: [
        'my-content-script'
      ],

      // extendBexScriptsConf (esbuildConf) {}
      // extendBexManifestJson (json) {}
    }
  }
});
```